# Extract the value from a array using date condition in excel which is repeated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iHhU2su03CVoEbSYb-nnd35ujd-maA4h/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105805963750341904121&rtpof=true&sd=true)
I have a file in that, I want to extract the payroll present or absent in that I get date column employees Id.
Problem is, I want to extract which employee is present on a particular date. Example 19-03-2022 in that date I want to extract data of employee id
THIS IS ONE TABLE.

| Emp. Id. | 19-03-2022 |
| --- | --- |
| 66 |  |
| 95 |  |
| 19 |  |
| 11 |  |
| 6945 |  |

ANOTHER TABLE IS :-

| EMPLOYEE ID | DOJ | PRESENT | WORKING DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 66 | 28-02-2022 | 1 | 16-03-2022 |
| 66 | 28-02-2022 | 1 | 17-03-2022 |
| 66 | 28-02-2022 | 1 | 18-03-2022 |
| **66** | 28-02-2022 | 1 | **19-03-2022** |
| 66 | 28-02-2022 | 1 | 20-03-2022 |
| 66 | 28-02-2022 | 1 | 21-03-2022 |
| 66 | 28-02-2022 | 1 | 22-03-2022 |
| 66 | 28-02-2022 | 1 | 23-03-2022 |

I want to extract, this employee is actually present or not in that particular date.
If any solution for that, pls help me. I am in a big trouble.

Payout Sheets problem.
Please see this sheet tab and solve my problem.
If you want to see read me all problem are discussed.

Comment: We can't access your linked sheet at the moment

Comment: Please use the following to create markdown tables: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables I fixed 1 table I didn't understand the other.

Comment: It's also unclear to me what you want to "extract". Do you want the number of times listed ID's are present or the sum? Total or per ID? In example data result would be 1?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `INDEX/MATCH()` should work for you.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$9,MATCH(1,($E$2:$E$9=A3)*($H$2:$H$9=$B$2),0)),"Absent")
```

You may need array entry the formula with `CRTL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: Thank You So much, You save my lots of time sir. You are amazing. Hats Off sir. Harun24hr really you are good man.

Comment: @STIPHENJOHN Glad to know. If it helps then tick mark the answer (accept it as solved).